# UITableView separator disappears when setup it programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, tableview

I trying to hide separator for last and single cell in section.
My method cellForRow look like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: UITableViewCell.self), for: indexPath)
    
    if dataSource.count - 1 == indexPath.row {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    } else {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

It works, but in some cases when else block executed, separator still invisible. It happens when cell which was last, reuse for middle cell, but i don't understand why updated separator inset is not applied.
What could be the reason of this issue?

Comment: What on earth is `UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)` supposed to do? That's no way to talk.

Comment: it supposed to hide separator

Comment: I don't want hide separators for whole table, I want hide it only for single and last cell in section. Separator style .none apply for whole table only.